# Is it a good idea to register multiple domains pointing to a single website

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, multiple-domains, analytics

We have a main domain or primary domain (say xyz.com) on which we have our website hosted. For the sake of business/trademark we would like to book other domain with the same name but different tlds (say xyz.org, xyz.net, xyz.info etc). Also to refrain our competitors using most commonly used domain names of our common products, we would like to book 20-25 more domain related to our product line.

We don't want to duplicate the content of the primary website for all these domains. We want all domains to shown the same content. How can this be achieved? I have heard that duplicate content across multiple domain is considered spamming by search engines. Many website have suggested 301 redirect.

I have opened this questions to know more about pros and cons of any of the approaches which would shown the content of our website from any of these domains and also help us in page ranking. Also what would be the impact on the SEO front using any approach.

I would also like to know, how am I going to track which website user comes using which URL.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as all the secondary domains simply do a 301 Permanent Redirect to the primary domain, this will not negatively affect SEO at all. It probably wont have any positive effects either, but if you value owning those domains (even if just to ensure noone else uses them) then that may be immaterial.

Replicating the content on all the different domains will however negatively affect your SEO and should be avoided. This approach also invites user fragmentation. You will have to retain all the different domains (even if you discontinue a product line) as users may have memorized *that* domain. It could also lead to marketing confusion.

You could also just register and not use those domains, but as doing redirects is essentially free you might as well have them in place.